# What is the determinant of a null matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What is the determinat of a null matrix of dimension $n×n$?

Comment: The determinant of the matrix $A=0$ is simply $0$ , no matter what $n$ is.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if any square matrix has one row or one column of zeroes, its determinant is zero. Yours is a special case of this statement, which is easily checked by cofactor expansion.